# mongoDB database.collection throwing error 'not a function' - MERN app

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, reactjs, express

Trying to connect to a MongoDB while following along with a tutorial from 2014 - they are using a different version of everything so some of the features are not aligning. I am currently encountering an issue where my MongoDB will not connect - I have copied almost everything exact as the tutorial with one minor change which shouldn't have affected anything and it still will not work. I have found similar issues but the app was so different, the solutions didn't work.

The error I am receiving when i npm start:

```
/rgr-stack/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:810
        throw err;
        ^

TypeError: database.collection is not a function
at MongoClient.connect (/Users/km/Desktop/rgr-stack/server.js:14:14)
at args.push (/Users/km/Desktop/rgr-stack/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:404:72)
at /Users/km/Desktop/rgr-stack/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:255:5
at connectCallback (/Users/km/Desktop/rgr-stack/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:933:5)
at /Users/km/Desktop/rgr-stack/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:807:13
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! rgrjs@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the rgrjs@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/km/.npm/_logs/2018-01-07T04_04_32_443Z-debug.log
```

Here are my steps:

```
export MONGO_URL=mongodb://rg***:******@ds241737.mlab.com:41737/rgr-stack
```

Here is my server (which is set up just like the demo):

```
const express = require('express');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

let app = express();

// var url = 'export  MONGO_URL=mongodb://rg***:******@ds241737.mlab.com:41737/rgr-stack'

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.listen(3000);

MongoClient.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, (err, database) => {
  if (err) throw err;

database.collection("links").find({}).toArray((err, links) => {
    if (err) throw err;

    console.log(links);
    })
})
```

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "rgrjs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "a collection of educational resources about React, GraphQL, and Relay",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/krisxcrash/rgr-stack.git"
  },
  "author": "kristine martin",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/krisxcrash/rgr-stack/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/krisxcrash/rgr-stack#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "create-react-class": "^15.6.2",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "kerberos": "0.0.23",
    "mongodb": "^3.0.1",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since version 3.0, `Mongo` have updated their API, `connect` function is no longer return a `db` object but now a `MongoClient` that can be used to get access to the database. You should change your code to something like:

```
MongoClient.connect('[MONGO_CONNECTION_STRING]', (err, client) => {
  // Client returned
  var db = client.db('[YOUR_DB]');
});
```

For more information, have a look at the changelog: 
https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/3.0.0/CHANGES_3.0.0.md